# How to set background image for a link?

Tags: html, css

The code below is a link which has a class through which I want to add a background image. I am not able to display background image however same code sets background color correctly so what I am missing here? I don't want to use `<img>` tag inside link because I want to change background image on hover.

```css
.dropbtn{background: url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/356/cubes-1425949.jpg) 50px 50px no-repeat;}
```

```html
<a class="dropbtn">image</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Class for background image]
See Clearly i used class and in css,me use background-image.It is not necessary to do 1 thing from only one method.there are many options to do any anything

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.Wrap the `<a>` with a `div` then `style` below this way.Hope this will help you.

```css
.hello {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/356/cubes-1425949.jpg);
  height: 700px
}
```

```html
<div class="hello"><a class="dropbtn">image</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing 50px 50px
Is your link 50px heigh?
My guess is that you should start with 0 0 and see where the image is. Is there a lot of transparent or white space on the canvas so the actual image is not in view especially with the 50px right and top positions added also?

Add height to your link and remove the image positioning by using left top.

Answer (score -1):

you are using wrong class for css
use below code

.dropbtn{background-image:url(http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/356/cubes-1425949.jpg) 50px 50px no-repeat;

Comment: You cannot use positioning with background-image: only background:

Comment: Why the negative??? You are incorrect! You cannot add a position using background-image: url (smiley.png) left top; will NOT work only background: url (smiley.png) left top; or use background-position. Do your homework before giving negative feedback.

Comment: Try it yourself here: - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position

Comment: see above picture in the answer

Comment: Go and add positions of "left top" to the end of that line and it will not render the image :) All I am saying is that your syntax cannot contain positions with using background-image, only background.